# C program gets linker errors. I really can't see what's wrong

Tags: c, linker

I am having trouble with a code of mine. I am using Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2...
The problem is LINKER ERROR and I know that usually linker errors are something common that 
The linker errors are as follows:maybe I have overlooked but seriously I dont know what's wrong!

[Linker error] undefined reference to `getUniqueNumber'

[Linker error] undefined reference to `straight_select_int'

[Linker error] undefined reference to `straight_insert_int'

[Linker error] undefined reference to `bubblesort_int'

[Linker error] undefined reference to `quicksort_int'

ld returned 1 exit status

U:\My Documents\alg\AlgProject\ALG\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [Project1.exe] Error 1

Anyhoo, this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <dos.h>

# define N 30000

void bubblesort_int(int p[]); 
void quicksort_int(int left, int right, int p[]);
void straight_select_int(int p[]);
void straight_insert_int(int p[]);
int getUniqueNumber(int *p, int i);



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int p[N],pA[N];

int i,j,x;

time_t t0,t1;



for (j=0; j<10; j++)
{
   srand(time(0));

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        p[i]=getUniqueNumber(p,i);
    }

  for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        pA[i] = p[i];
    }

       time(&t0);     
  straight_select_int(p); 
  time(&t1);
  x=difftime(t1,t0);



    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        p[i]=pA[i];
    }

    time(&t0);    
    straight_insert_int(p); 
    time(&t1);
    x=difftime(t1,t0);





    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        p[i]=pA[i];
    }


    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    p[i]=pA[i];    

    time(&t0);     
    bubblesort_int(p);  
    time(&t1);
    x=difftime(t1,t0);



    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        p[i]=pA[i];
    }

    time(&t0);     
    quicksort_int(0, N-1, p);  
    time(&t1);
    x=difftime(t1,t0);





   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
   getch();
   }
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


   void straight_select_int(int p[]);
   {
   int i,j,k,min;

   for (i=0; i<N-1; i++)
   {
    k = i;
    min = p[i];
    for (j = i+1; j<N; j++)
        {
     if (p[j] < min)
        {
           k = j;
            min = p[j];
        }
     }
     p[k] = p[i] ;
     p[i] = min;
    }
   }
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


   void straight_insert_int(int p[])
    {
    int i,j,x;
    for (i = 1; i < N; i++)
       {
           x = p[i];
           j = i-1;
           while ((x < p[j]) && (j >= 0))
            {
                p[j+1] = p[j] ;
                j = j-1 ;
            }
            p[j+1] = x ;
       }
 }


  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



void bubblesort_int(int p[])
{
int i,j,temp;
for (i=1; i<N; i++)
   for (j=N-1; j>=i; j--)
     if (p[j-1] > p[j])
       {
         temp = p[j-1];
         p[j-1] = p[j] ;
         p[j] = temp ;
       }


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


void quicksort_int(int left, int right, int p[])
{
 int i, j, mid, x, temp;
  if (left < right)
    {
       i = left;
       j = right;
       mid = (left+right)/2;
       x = p[mid];
       while (i < j)
          {
             while (p[i] < x)
             i++;
             while (p[j] > x)
                 j--;
             if (i < j)
                {
                   if (p[i] == p[j])
                     {
                       if (i<mid)
                           i++;
                           if (j>mid)
                              j--;
                     }
                   else
                      {
                         temp = p[i];
                         p[i] = p[j];
                         p[j] = temp;
                      }
                  }
          }
       quicksort_int(left,j-1,p);
       quicksort_int(j+1,right,p);
     }


}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int getUniqueNumber(int *p, int i)
{
int x,j, found;

do
{
    x = rand();
    found = 0;
    j = 0;
    while (j<=i && found == 0)
    {
        if (p[j] == x)
        {
            found = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
        }
    }
}
while (found == 1);
return x;
}
}
}
```

thanks in advance guys... if the answer is simple and stupid forgive me because its late! 
:/ :P

Comment: Is this all in one file? Why is this tagged Xcode?

Comment: You never close `main()`. I'm somewhat surprised this compiles.

Comment: Here's why it compiles: `void straight_select_int(int p[]);` <-----

Comment: This prototype has a semi-colon, which is good: `void straight_select_int(int p[]);`.  But scroll down to the implementation and you'll see the implementation also has the semi-colon, which is bad.  Remove that.

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains all function bodies defined inside `main()`. This is not permitted in standard C. Some compilers offer it as an extension, but the local function `main::straight_insert_int` inside `main()` is a different entity to the free function `straight_insert_int`.

This is why you get the linker error; you never defined the free function `straight_insert_int`.

To fix this, change your code structure to be:

```
int main()
{
     // main's code here
}

void straight_insert_int(int p[])
{
    // straight_insert_int's code here
}

void bubblesort_int(int p[])
{
    //bubblesort_int's code here
}
```

etc.

If you use a consistent style of indentation like this then you will find it easier to keep your braces straight.  Some text editors also have a key command that will take you to the corresponding brace if you press it on one brace.

Answer (score 0):

The question code mostly has flaws with braces.  Here is the code formatted a little better.  It compiles and links properly now. *However, it does not properly execute. (or, perhaps it does exactly what is intended?)*

In any case, the linker errors (the point of the question) are resolved.  If you require further assistance to figure out why the code does not properly execute, perhaps you should post the code in a new question.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
//#include <dos.h> non-portable

# define N 30000

void bubblesort_int(int p[]);
void quicksort_int(int left, int right, int p[]);
void straight_select_int(int p[]);
void straight_insert_int(int p[]);
int getUniqueNumber(int *p, int i);


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
   int p[N],pA[N];
   int i,j,x;
   time_t t0,t1;

   for (j=0; j<10; j++)
      {
      srand(time(0));
      }                  // +++ Added this line.

   for(i=0;i<N;i++)
      {
      p[i]=getUniqueNumber(p,i);
      }

   for (i=0; i<N; i++)
      {
      pA[i] = p[i];
      }

   time(&t0);
   straight_select_int(p);
   time(&t1);
   x=difftime(t1,t0);

   for(i=0;i<N;i++)
      {
      p[i]=pA[i];
      }

   time(&t0);
   straight_insert_int(p);
   time(&t1);
   x=difftime(t1,t0);

   for(i=0;i<N;i++)
      {
      p[i]=pA[i];
      }

   for (i=0;i<N;i++)
      p[i]=pA[i];

   time(&t0);
   bubblesort_int(p);
   time(&t1);
   x=difftime(t1,t0);

   for(i=0;i<N;i++)
      {
      p[i]=pA[i];
      }

   time(&t0);
   quicksort_int(0, N-1, p);
   time(&t1);
   x=difftime(t1,t0);

//   system("PAUSE");  Not needed.
   return 0;
//   getch();  Non-portable, and also beyond the return code is not executed.
   }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void straight_select_int(int p[])   // --- Removed: ';' at the end of this line.
   {
   int i,j,k,min;

   for (i=0; i<N-1; i++)
      {
      k = i;
      min = p[i];
      for (j = i+1; j<N; j++)
         {
         if (p[j] < min)
            {
            k = j;
            min = p[j];
            }
         }

      p[k] = p[i] ;
      p[i] = min;
      }

   return;
   }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void straight_insert_int(int p[])
   {
   int i,j,x;

   for (i = 1; i < N; i++)
      {
      x = p[i];
      j = i-1;

      while ((x < p[j]) && (j >= 0))
         {
         p[j+1] = p[j] ;
         j = j-1 ;
         }

      p[j+1] = x ;
      }

   return;
   }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void bubblesort_int(int p[])
   {
   int i,j,temp;

   for (i=1; i<N; i++)
      for (j=N-1; j>=i; j--)
         if (p[j-1] > p[j])
            {
            temp = p[j-1];
            p[j-1] = p[j] ;
            p[j] = temp ;
            }
   return;       // +++ Added this line.
   }             // +++ Added this line.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void quicksort_int(int left, int right, int p[])
   {
   int i, j, mid, x, temp;

   if(left < right)
      {
      i = left;
      j = right;
      mid = (left+right)/2;
      x = p[mid];
      while (i < j)
         {
         while (p[i] < x)
            i++;

         while (p[j] > x)
            j--;

         if (i < j)
            {
            if (p[i] == p[j])
               {
               if (i<mid)
                  i++;

               if (j>mid)
                  j--;
               }
            else
               {
               temp = p[i];
               p[i] = p[j];
               p[j] = temp;
               }
            }
         }

      quicksort_int(left,j-1,p);
      quicksort_int(j+1,right,p);
      }

   return;
   }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int getUniqueNumber(int *p, int i)
   {
   int x,j, found;

   do {
      x = rand();
      found = 0;
      j = 0;
      while (j<=i && found == 0)
         {
         if (p[j] == x)
            {
            found = 1;
            }
         else
            {
            j++;
            }
         }
      } while(found == 1);

   return x;
   }
// --- removed: '}'
// --- removed: '}'
```

PS; user3670661, if you are really serious about becoming a programmer, you need to take more pride in your code.  The code posted in the question lacks consistent style.. There are many ways to lay-out code; you need to pick an acceptable lay-out style and make it a habit when you code. Just aligning your open and close braces is the first step to debugging the code.  Good luck! --Mahonri

Comment: @user3670661, That's just the way it goes sometimes.  Remember; eternity is a very long time... but not as long as it was yesterday.